# Deprecated functionality: preg_replace()

Tags: magento-1.8, php, php-5.6, deprecated

Trying my instance of Magento on PHP 5.6 because my host is upgrading the server and everything seems to work well besides from this error message.

> Deprecated functionality: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is
>   deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead  in
>   /public_html/lib/Zend/Filter/PregReplace.php on line 171

Has anyone successfully patched this file?

Comment: There is no and never was a `/e` modifier in this file, so why would you want to patch it?

Comment: I believe your correct its not in that file itself, but I believe extensions call this function and pass values to it

Comment: Exactly, so you need to trace the pattern origin and either fix it yourself or ask the extension vendor for an update that supports PHP 5.6.

Comment: By the way, the `/e` modifier is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0, see [function.preg-replace](http://php.net/preg_replace).